# FullCalendar V6 (Angular) with Timegrid plugin- how to hide "All-Day", CalendarOptions doesn't have "allDaySlot" option?

Tags: angular, angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm having trouble using a defined parameter referred to in the documentation here

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/allDaySlot

When I try to use the option in the options override, the option is not recognized.

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedule',
  templateUrl: './schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule.component.scss']
})
export class ScheduleComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    cal?: Calendar;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.createCalendar()
    }

    private createCalendar(){
        const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')

        if(calendarEl){
            this.cal = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                headerToolbar: false,
                plugins: [timeGridPlugin],
                editable: false,
                nowIndicator: true,
                allDaySlot: false,
                initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
                dayHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'long' },
                events: [ 
                    { title: 'Meeting', start: new Date() }
                ]
            })
        }

     ...
```

The error is: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'allDaySlot' does not exist in type 'CalendarOptions'

The versions I have installed are as follows:

```
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.8",
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Found additional information in the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options

The plugin/view specific option needs to be in the views object like so:

```
this.cal = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                headerToolbar: false,
                plugins: [timeGridPlugin],
                editable: false,
                nowIndicator: true,
                initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
                dayHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'long' },

                views:{
                    timeGridWeek:{
                        allDaySlot: false,
                    }
                },

                events: [
                    { title: 'Meeting', start: new Date() }
                ]
            })
```